# Can't switch to virtual consoles as usual

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nixos, virtual-consoles

On previous Ubuntu and now NixOS on Dell Inspiron-7559, I have found that the virtual consoles are unusual compared to Thinkpad.

1. I found that I have to press Fn besides the normal key bindings, i.e. Fn+Ctrl+Alt+F_i. But an exception is that Ctrl+Alt+F_4  also works.
2. When I press Fn+Ctrl+Alt+F_i, from i=1 to 7, I can switch to tty_i only for i = 1 to 4, not for i = 5 to 7.
3. When I press Fn+Ctrl+Alt+F_i, from i=7 to 1, I can switch to tty_i only for i = 6 to 5, not for i=7 and not for i = 4 to 1.
4. So far I don't know how to switch to tty7.

I was wondering why? What can I do about it?

Answer (score 0):

By tradition/historical reasons all major distributives set up just four tty consoles and 7th is reserved for graphic UI.

If you want to change it, loot at man for syslogd.conf(5).
And/or `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`
It specifies how many tty's to have and which one is GUI.